# Reading text in r within quotes

Tags: r

I am trying to read a loaded variable within quotations in r.

```
criterion1 <- colnames(Test1[9])
dlgInput(message = "Input Criterion for "criterion1"")$res
```

This is currently what I was trying but it does not work. I want the input box to have the column name at the specified location. I was wondering if there is any way for r to read and pull from the variable within the quotations.

I would like the input box to read "Input Criterion for 'contents within criterion1'"

Thanks

Comment: Try: `"Input Criterion for \"criterion1\""`

Comment: That did not work but it was close I will look for more escape commands. Thanks, I hadn't thought of the forward slash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like these four ways, which produce  `Input Criterion for 'am'`.

```
criterion1 <- colnames(mtcars)[9]

str1 <- paste0("Input Criterion for '", criterion1, "'.")
str2 <- sprintf("Input Criterion for '%s'", criterion1)
str3 <- glue::glue("Input Criterion for '{column_name}'", column_name=criterion1)
str4 <- glue::glue("Input Criterion for '{criterion1}'")
```

In future posts, consider using a dataset that's easily accessible by everyone, and stripping out things that are an unnecessary to your core question, like the `dlgInput()` and the `$res` are here (assuming I'm understanding correctly now).

#### Original response

either escape the double quote (`str1`), or enclose with single quotes (`str2`).

```
str1 <- "Input Criterion for \"criterion1\""
str2 <- 'Input Criterion for \"criterion1\"'
```

result:

```
> cat(str1)
Input Criterion for "criterion1"
> cat(str2)
Input Criterion for "criterion1"
```

I'm surprised there's not a duplicate hit on SO for "[r] escape quote"

Comment: Ah it is close but I am trying to read in the column name that I grabbed in the code              criterion1 <- colnames(Test1[9])                        
within the Dlginput

Comment: Wow, amazing you are a wizard! I will prepare my questions with your advice going forward, thanks! (I am relatively new to this site)